# Ubuntu on WSL Windows 10 comes up to a blinking cursor

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Folks,

1. Ubuntu on WSL Windows 10 was working fine.
2. Today it just comes up with a blinking cursor.
3. Uninstalled Ubuntu and reinstalled it again

Current Ubuntu Version : 2002.4.4.0
Windows version  : 10.0.19044
WSL Version : 5.10.102.1
BIOS Version/Date   LENOVO N2IET90W (1.68 ), 7/6/2020

Still have a blinking cursor in the top corner.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Can you edit your question to fix the formatting and version numbers?  "5.10.102.1" isn't a WSL version (it's a kernel version); "2002.4.40" isn't an Ubuntu version (I'm not sure what it is supposed to be).  The Windows version is off in a code-block when it shouldn't be.